# Unable to run bokehjs code because bokehjs library is missing

Tags: django, bokeh

Id like to embed a graph with bokeh, but I get a page with the unrendered graph on it.

home.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.3.4.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-1.3.4.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-1.3.4.min.css"/>

<div class="container text-center">
        <h1>HELLO</h1>
        {{ div }}
        {{ script }}
</div>
</body>

<script text="type/javascript" src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.3.4.min.js"></script>
<script text="type/javascript" src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-1.3.4.min.js"></script>
<script text="type/javascript" src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-1.3.4.min.js"></script>
<script text="type/javascript" src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-api-1.3.4.min.js"></script>
```

---

views

```
def home(request):
    x= [1,3,5,7,9,11,13]
    y= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    title = 'y = f(x)'

    plot = figure(title= title , 
        x_axis_label= 'X-Axis', 
        y_axis_label= 'Y-Axis', 
        plot_width =400,
        plot_height =400)

    plot.line(x, y, legend= 'f(x)', line_width = 2)
    #Store components 
    script, div = components(plot)

    #Feed them to the Django template.
    return render_to_response( 'bokehApp/home.html',
            {'script' : script , 'div' : div} )
```

---

Result

```
<div class="bk-root" id="5456b4a3-69cc-4962-8afe-31be08905f6b" data-root-id="1001"></div> <script type="text/javascript"> (function() { var fn = function() { Bokeh.safely(function() { (function(root) { function embed_document(root) { var docs_json = '{"ed1a0b2a-1947-447e-8898-9a0c6f7ca346":{"roots":{"references":[{"attributes":{"bottom_units":"screen","fill_alpha":{"value":0.5},"fill_color":{"value":"lightgrey"},"left_units":"screen","level":"overlay","line_alpha":{"value":1.0},"line_color":{"value":"black"},"line_dash":[4,4],"line_width":{"value":2},"render_mode":"css","right_units":"screen","top_units":"screen"},"id":"1045","type":"BoxAnnotation"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1053","type":"Selection"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1054","type":"UnionRenderers"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"1035","type":"ColumnDataSource"},"glyph":{"id":"1036","type":"Line"},"hover_glyph":null,"muted_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"1037","type":"Line"},"selection_glyph":null,"view":{"id":"1039","type":"CDSView"}},"id":"1038","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{"source":{"id":"1035","type":"ColumnDataSource"}},"id":"1039","type":"CDSView"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1018","type":"BasicTicker"},{"attributes":{"ticker":{"id":"1013","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"1016","type":"Grid"},{"attributes":{"axis_label":"Y-Axis","formatter":{"id":"1044","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},"ticker":{"id":"1018","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"1017","type":"LinearAxis"},{"attributes":{"line_color":"#1f77b4","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1036","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.1,"line_color":"#1f77b4","line_width":2,"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"1037","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"axis_label":"X-Axis","formatter":{"id":"1042","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},"ticker":{"id":"1013","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"1012","type":"LinearAxis"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1013","type":"BasicTicker"},{"attributes":{"overlay":{"id":"1045","type":"BoxAnnotation"}},"id":"1024","type":"BoxZoomTool"},{"attributes":{"callback":null,"data":{"x":[1,3,5,7,9,11,13],"y":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]},"selected":{"id":"1053","type":"Selection"},"selection_policy":{"id":"1054","type":"UnionRenderers"}},"id":"1035","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{"label":{"value":"f(x)"},"renderers":[{"id":"1038","type":"GlyphRenderer"}]},"id":"1047","type":"LegendItem"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1025","type":"SaveTool"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1042","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1027","type":"HelpTool"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1026","type":"ResetTool"},{"attributes":{"dimension":1,"ticker":{"id":"1018","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"1021","type":"Grid"},{"attributes":{"items":[{"id":"1047","type":"LegendItem"}]},"id":"1046","type":"Legend"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1023","type":"WheelZoomTool"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1022","type":"PanTool"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1010","type":"LinearScale"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1044","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},{"attributes":{"active_drag":"auto","active_inspect":"auto","active_multi":null,"active_scroll":"auto","active_tap":"auto","tools":[{"id":"1022","type":"PanTool"},{"id":"1023","type":"WheelZoomTool"},{"id":"1024","type":"BoxZoomTool"},{"id":"1025","type":"SaveTool"},{"id":"1026","type":"ResetTool"},{"id":"1027","type":"HelpTool"}]},"id":"1028","type":"Toolbar"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1008","type":"LinearScale"},{"attributes":{"callback":null},"id":"1006","type":"DataRange1d"},{"attributes":{"callback":null},"id":"1004","type":"DataRange1d"},{"attributes":{"text":"y = f(x)"},"id":"1002","type":"Title"},{"attributes":{"below":[{"id":"1012","type":"LinearAxis"}],"center":[{"id":"1016","type":"Grid"},{"id":"1021","type":"Grid"},{"id":"1046","type":"Legend"}],"left":[{"id":"1017","type":"LinearAxis"}],"plot_height":400,"plot_width":400,"renderers":[{"id":"1038","type":"GlyphRenderer"}],"title":{"id":"1002","type":"Title"},"toolbar":{"id":"1028","type":"Toolbar"},"x_range":{"id":"1004","type":"DataRange1d"},"x_scale":{"id":"1008","type":"LinearScale"},"y_range":{"id":"1006","type":"DataRange1d"},"y_scale":{"id":"1010","type":"LinearScale"}},"id":"1001","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"}],"root_ids":["1001"]},"title":"Bokeh Application","version":"1.3.4"}}'; var render_items = [{"docid":"ed1a0b2a-1947-447e-8898-9a0c6f7ca346","roots":{"1001":"5456b4a3-69cc-4962-8afe-31be08905f6b"}}]; root.Bokeh.embed.embed_items(docs_json, render_items); } if (root.Bokeh !== undefined) { embed_document(root); } else { var attempts = 0; var timer = setInterval(function(root) { if (root.Bokeh !== undefined) { embed_document(root); clearInterval(timer); } attempts++; if (attempts > 100) { console.log("Bokeh: ERROR: Unable to run BokehJS code because BokehJS library is missing"); clearInterval(timer); } }, 10, root) } })(window); }); }; if (document.readyState != "loading") fn(); else document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn); })(); </script>
```

---

bokeh.**version**
u'1.3.4'

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `safe` filter:

```
{{ div|safe }}
{{ script|safe }}
```

Otherwise, Jinja will escape everything to be HTML-safe (i.e. non-executable) before it is templated.